# Problem manually calling dotnet test on playwright tests generated by specflow

Tags: c#, .net, shell, automated-tests, specflow

I'm working on a C# project that's using specflow with playwright to handle most of our testing, and I'm trying to set up a way to generate playwright trace files only for tests that have failed.  Right now I'm printing the name of each test that fails to a .txt file, then using a shell script to manually call dotnet test on each test in that file at the end of our test run with playwright trace generation enabled.  This works fine for tests that have a simple name, such as "FillInAllFieldsOnPage", but if a test that is generated from a scenario outline using examples fails it gives me an error.  I believe this is due to the way that dotnet test is parsing the name of the test, as specflow generates the name in the format

```
CheckSortingAndDataInHoverMenu("C, User",null)
```

where "C, User" is one of the examples given to the Scenario Outline.  I've tried adding a line that reformats the string to be more in line with what I've seen recommended elsewhere, so that the end result looks like this:

```
CheckSortingAndDataInHoverMenu(\"C%2C User\"%2Cnull)
```

but I still get the following error:

```
Running dotnet test on "CheckSortingAndDataInHoverMenu(\"C%2C User\"%2Cnull)"
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: User"%2Cnull)
```

I've verified that the .csproj file does exist, and other tests are able to be run from that command so I know it's being called from the correct directory.  It looks like dotnet test thinks that "User"%2Cnull)" is a name for a .csproj file that I'm passing it as an arg, and I don't know how to get it to properly process the full test name.

Comment: The %2C is indicating a filename contains a comma (0x2c).  why do you have a project name with a comma in the name?

Comment: That's not the name of the project, it's just the name of the test that's generated by specflow when you use the Scenario Outline/Example pattern

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to this was to simply remove the part of the test name in parenthesis, which caused the dotnet test command to run every test with a matching name.  I then added a random guid to the name of each test trace that was generated in order to prevent them from overwriting eachother.